# chrome拡張機能で画面分割したい

Tags: google-chrome, chrome-extension

やりたい事としては、メインで普通にブラウジングしつつ、サブの画面ではあらかじめ用意したhtmlを読み込んでメニューとして使いたいと考えています。
popupにするとメインの画面を操作すると消えてしまうので使い勝手が悪くなってしまいます。

Comment: 面白いと思いますけど、質問は何ですか？

Comment: chrome拡張機能で画面を分割して一方に指定したhtmlを読ませる方法がわからず、困っています

Answer (score 1):

Firefox でいうサイドバーのようなものでしょうか？

> Firefox のサイドバーを使用して、ブックマークや履歴、ソーシャル機能にアクセスする
>   http://mzl.la/1GSQjHi

現在のところ Chrome 拡張では実現不可能ですが、要望はあがっています。近い将来、実現されるかもしれません。

> Issue 51084 - chromium - Add sidebar surface for extensions - An open-source project to help move the web forward. - Google Project Hosting
>   https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=51084

Answer (score 1):

あまり勧められるやり方ではありませんが、Content Scriptを使えば、任意のWebページの内容を編集してしまうことができます。それを使えば、強引にサイドバー的なものを挿入してしまうこともできるでしょう。

例えば、Githubが表示されたことを検知して、Content Scriptを使ってGithubのプロジェクト内のファイルツリーを左側に出す、という拡張機能があります。

https://github.com/buunguyen/octotree

このように「限定されたWebページに対してサイドバーを設けることでUXを向上させる」といったものであれば、嬉しいユーザもいるのかな、と思います。